# Sum of all the numbers that can be formed using all the digits $2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the sum of all the numbers that can be formed using all the digits $2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4$.

It is a P&C related problem so the word all means it is a six-digit number.
Hence the number of terms is $\frac{6!}{3!2!} = 60$.

How do I calculate the sum?

Comment: There are $60$ such numbers.  Half of them have $4$ in any given position.  $\frac 13$ of them have $3$ in any given position and $\frac 16$ of them have $2$ in a position.  So the sum is $60*(\frac 12*444444+\frac 23*333333+\frac 16*222222)$.

Answer (score 5):

Well $30$ of the $60$ number have $4$ in the ones place, $20$ have $3$ in the ones place and $10$ have $2$ in the ones place.

So the ones place add to $30\times 4 + 20\times 3 + 10\times 2= 120+60 + 20= 200$.

The same is true for every position so every position add to $200$ so the sum is $22222200$.